# Edges creation is not working in gremlin python

Tags: cosmos, gremlinpython

Trying to *create edges between vertices* using *gremlin-python*, but it is not working

jupyter notebook

```
"g.V('ProdDev').addE('belongs').to(g.V('Dept'))"
```

edges should create....currently empty edges are creating...

Comment: Can you also post some examples of your data?

Comment: "g.addV('ProductDevelopment').property('ProductDevID',"+"012345").property('ProductDevName',"+"skinny") "                                                                               "g.addV('Season').property('Season',2019)"                                                                                                     created two vertices using this gremlin query, now I need to create edge between vertices. For that I'm using query as  "g.V('ProductDev').addE('belongs').to(g.V('Season'))" but edge is not creating in database

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
g.addV('Season')
```

that creates a vertex with the `label` Season.

However, when you use

```
g.V('Season')
```

Gremlin is looking for a vertex with an ID (not a label) of Season.

If you need to use the label you can do

```
g.V().hasLabel('Season')
```

Also, mid traversal, you should not use `g.V()` rather you should do

```
to(V().hasLabel('Season'))
```